# calling a project with using or project name

Tags: c#, oop, using

Is it better to use a class of another C# project by its class name. Like this

```
 Buss_Logic.Class1 myClass1 = new Buss_Logic.Class1();
 Buss_Logic.Class2 myClass2 = new Buss_Logic.Class2();
```

OR by `using` keyword on top of the file

```
 using Buss_Logic;
```

Answer (score 5):

As long as there is no namespace collision, it makes for more compact / easier to read code to include namespaces with the `using` keyword.

If there is ever any doubt as to where the class is defined, hover the mouse over the class name.  The tool tip will show the fully qualified class name.

Use explicit namespaces if there is a namespace conflict (e.g. two classes called `File` in two different namespaces, where both classes are needed in the current source document).

Answer (score 2):

Use a `using` at the top of the file as long as there are no conflicts in the names.

Given that the class themselves are clear enough, it makes the code easier to read.